# Is it possible to make uitableheader passes just over the first tablecell?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, header

i have a simple uitableview with tableHeaderView. i have more than one section.

i set the headerview's height 30. but i want to use 40 pixel height uiview in my header (from 0,0 to 320,30 not transparent. from 30,10 to 320,40 is transparent). i put a picture in it. there is a small icon on point(0x30). its height=10.
i just want to show my headerview just a little bit over on the first tablecell.

you will see below that i set header's height to 30, but i create 40 pixel height view in viewForHeaderInSection.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 30;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {


    UIView *sectionView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];
    sectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [sectionView autorelease];
    return sectionView;

}
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Your sectionView will be limited by the height of header. Even if you use a UIView of 1000 pixels high, it will only be shown within the limits defined by the height of a table cell/header.

Comment: Impossible in my knowledge so far, unless someone comes up with a twisted workaround not found before.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I have an answer for your problem. I don't know if this is a good solution but I think it is okay.

I made a new empty xib file and put a UITableViewCell in that file. I changed the height of the UITableViewCell to 54 and put a UIView inside the UITableViewCell. The frame of the view is 0,0,320,10. Then I changed the file's owner of that xib file to my TableViewController.

```
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController {

UITableViewCell * firstCellInSection;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableViewCell * firstCellInSection;
@end
```

After that I connected the firstCellInSection Outlet with my UITableViewCell in the xib file.

Then I changed the code that the TableView loads this firstCell for all cells with

```
indexPath.row == 0
```

Here is the code:

```
@synthesize firstCellInSection;

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell * cell;
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        static NSString *firstCellInSectionIdentifier = @"FirstCellInSectionIdentifier";
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:firstCellInSectionIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FirstCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = firstCellInSection;
            self.firstCellInSection = nil;
        }
    }

}

else {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

}



// Configure the cell.
return cell;
}
```

Custom row height:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (indexPath.row == 0) return 54;

else return 44;
}
```

In combination with your code for the headerView it could look like you want.

Comment: i havent tried your solution yet. According to your solution, first cell will be bigger than others (10 px)?

Comment: i think there will one problem, if the user scrolls up, first cell goes away, every cell will be same.

Comment: I don't get your point. I thought you want just the section headers to be different. In my code every section begins with that firstCellInSection. When all cells should be custom then you need to make your own UITableViewCells. There are different ways to do that explained in the documentation. Edit: I forgot that the section view stays visible when have a plain TableView. In that case it doesn't work.

Comment: And for what reason the small icon can't be in the sectionView?

Comment: my problem is that i dont have a rectangle header for sections. thats why i did a picture on photoshop. pictures size is 320x40. pictures right-bottom side is transparent (from 10,30 to 320,40). if i can succeed to make headerview just over the first cell, it will solve my problem. when the user scroll up & down my little left-bottom corner (10x10 in headerview) will always stay there. i think it is impossible with uitableview.

Comment: small icon is already in section view. you can think small icon as a small arrow points downside.

Comment: And when you make your sectionView bigger? Of course it is still not over the cell but I can't imagine why this is a problem.

Comment: i think i didnt make it clear. let it be simple. 320x30 rectangle. and there is suffix ( a little arrow that points out down) picture (10x10). this arraw is just under the left-corner of rectangle (320x30). my header view size will be 320x40. if i set sections header height to 40, there will be no smooth appearance. i hope its clear now.

Comment: Maybe you can try to put the arrow in every cell you want and make it visible or not visible depending on its current position. Maybe you could also make an image with 320*30 where the arrow fits in the rect. Eventually it is possible to subclass UITableView and add a method for something like a second header view for sections